# An Access Problem:how to show records between two dates

Tags: ms-access

I have two combobox in my Access form named CombDate and CombDat1. Now I want to show records between two dates. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA, you can retrieve the values from the two date combo boxes and store them in date1 and date2, then you can open a recordset using VBA and DAO, with the following SQL:

```
"SELECT field1, field2 " & _ 
"FROM table " & _ 
"WHERE datefield > " & date1 & " AND datefield < " & date2 & ";"
```

More details would help clarify the solution, but that's the basic process.

Comment: Why would you open a recordset when you want to display the data in a form? You'd just assign the SQL string as the Recordsource property of the form. Also, there's no real advantage in using intermediate variables here -- you can just use the controls themselves. On the other hand, if you're going to allow the user to leave one of the two controls blank, you'll need to test, and in that case, additional variables might be helpful.